"Partition" in GParted
Regarding the answer to the question at
The creation of swap space in partition #3 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) failed,
what is meant by "Choose to lay down a GPT/GUID partition table"?
Is there a difference between "Delete" and "Format to clear" in "Partition" of GParted with respect to a particular partition
before the reinstallation of Ubuntu 18.04.6? Since the
functions are probably irreversible, I guess it is
important to know the difference, if any.
Also, is the elimination of the original partition table with GParted as a preparation for the reinstallation of Ubuntu 18.04.6 going to
leave intact or destroy the original factory-produced
Ubuntu 16.04 OS?
Thanks for any clarification.

Deleting a partition means removing the partition table entry for that partition. The diskspace used by that partition is actually untouched. If you don't take any further action after deleting a partition, the partition will be recoverable with appropriate tools like TestDisk, the software will scan for filesystem headers and recreates the partition table entry.
Formatting a partition will create a fresh filesystem in the partition. The data stored before in that partition are not accessible any more. Files stored on that partition may remain intact and are probably recoverable, but the directory structure is lost. So recovering data from a formatted partition can be a nightmare.
If you eliminate the partition table it means that you lose all partition table entries, the diskspace used by all partitions remains untouched but you cannot access the data stored there.  Deleting the partition table will render any OS installed on the disk unable to boot. This might be recoverable like described above. To sum it up, we could say deleting the partition table will partly destroy your factory-produced Ubuntu.
